# How to calculate a double trig integral with limits as x and y?

Tags: integration, trigonometry, cauchy-integral-formula, change-of-variable

How to go from
$$u(x,y) =\sin x+\sin y+\int_0^x d\xi \int_0^y \left( \cos(\xi\eta) -\xi \eta \sin(\xi\eta) \right) d\eta$$
to
$$u(x,y) = \sin(x) +\sin y+\sin(xy) $$
in full? This is an example for the solution to the Goursat problem.

Answer (score 0):

The $\eta$ integral gives $y \cos {\xi y}$, then the $\xi$ integral gives $\sin(xy)$ doing it by parts with $y$ and $\cos(\xi y)d\xi$

Comment: when doing by parts, you take u=EN and dv=sin(EN). which term do you differentiate and integrate with? e.g is u'=E or is u'=N

Comment: since you said you want the answer in full, i'm sure @Ross Millikan will explain the difference. but it really makes no difference. This isn't a chamge of variabels its just a dumy variable. (x,y) to (e,n). since u' is calculated w.r.t the derivative you want is w.r.t e. so u'=N.

Comment: When you have $y \cos \xi y$ you want to take $u=\xi, dv=\cos \xi y\ d\xi$ because differentiating $\xi$ makes it simpler and integrating the trig function leaves it the same complication.  Then $v\ du$ is \frac 1y\cos \xi y d\xi$ which is easy to integrate.

Comment: @RossMillikan im sorry i don't understand. could you show the integration by parts of the double integral above please.